# VB.NET - Getting list of all files in network resource

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.NET I need to get a list of all files in a network (NAS) folder. This seems really slow:

```
Dim searchFolder as string = "\\NAS\Tool files"
My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(searchFolder, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, sp).ToList
```

Is there a faster way?

EDIT: I should have mentioned that the network resource has over 100,000 files.

Comment: You could use the [Directory.EnumerateFiles Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. Don't materialise it as a list; instead, use it in a loop. That way you don't have to wait for the entire list to be returned in one go but you can still process it one item at a time.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - This worked far better than what I was doing. I ended up putting the file paths in a text file to be read later. I would need to do this a lot but (thankfully) the network resource is now static. I think what I will do is open the file I have saved, read them into a data structure (perhaps a hash?) and then use that to search for specific files. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A great question! I have been in a situation where I needed to iterate over close to 3 million files from a slow network storage area, read some data out of them and create database filepath pointers for each one. GetFiles was prohibitively slow in that use case.

The problem with **.GetFiles()** is that it performs the entire retrieval upfront before commencing your iteration.

A simple tweak would be to use **.EnumerateFiles()**, which has a similar usage, which will find the first file that matches the pattern and commence iteration immediately before moving onto the next. More on this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Depending what operation you're performing in each iteration, you may want to take a step into the land of threading - this is a bit more advanced but it'll allow you to perform operations in parallel which will bring you further speed gains.

Good luck!